# Отличие между циклами FOR в JS

Tags: javascript, циклы

Упорно не могу понять отличие между циклами:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) continue;
    alert(i);
}
```

И вот этим:

```
for (var i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        alert( i );
    }
}
```

Оба используют оператор «деление с остатком», и после выводят результат, но в 1 показывает только нечетные, а в другом - четные значения i.

Можете помочь в осознание, как так?

Comment: Соль в `continue` ;)

Comment: @Visman  А я-то думал, что соль в солонке...

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, *видимо `continue` - это такая солонка...*

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто рассмотрите два if предложения, записанные проще в одну строку.

В первом цикле имеем

```
if (i % 2 == 0) continue;
```

ф во втором цикле то же самое if предложение имеет вид

```
if (i % 2 == 0) alert( i );
```

То есть в первом цикле если условие истинно (`i` - четное число), то происходит переход на следующую итерацию цикла, минуя все то, что следует за этим предложением в теле цикла.

Во втором же цикле если условие истинно, то происходит вызов метода `alert`

Или чтобы было еще более понятно, вы могли бы эти циклы записать в виде эквивалентных им циклов и увидеть различие

Первый цикл эквивалентен следующему

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        continue; 
    }
    else {
        alert(i);
    }
}
```

А второй цикл эквивалентен следующему

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
        alert( i );
    }
    else {
        continue;
    }    
}
```

Как видите, они противоположны по действию друг другу (в обоих циклах для наглядности я сделал условие выполнения цикла идентичным: `for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++)`)

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на цикл внимательнее.

В первом идет вот такое сравнение:

```
if (i % 2 == 0) continue;
alert( i );
```

во втором - вот такое:

```
if (i % 2 == 0) alert( i );
```

Оператор `continue` в первом цикле прерывает текущую итерацию выполнения цикла и переходит к следующей (начиная с увеличения `i`). Поэтому строка `alert( i );` выполняется только тогда, когда условие не выполняется.