# Вывод простых чисел в JS

Tags: javascript, циклы

Данный код предназначен для вывода простых чисел, я не могу понять как он пошагово работает:

```
nextPrime:
for (var i = 2; i < 10; i++) {

  for (var j = 2; j < i; j++) {
    if (i % j == 0) continue nextPrime;
  }

  alert( i ); // простое
}
```

Идет цикл для i, т.е.

- идет проверка j < i, в данном случает это неверно 2<2
- идет дальше выполнение alert и выводит 2
- i увеличивается на 1
- идет проверка 2<3, проходит дальше
- остается остаток 1
- выполняется alert (3)
- переменные увеличиваются на 1
- 3<4
- alert (4)
- еще увеличение 4<5
- alert (5)
  и т.д.

Но все не так.
По идее шаг: `i/j++` выполняется после тела на каждой итерации, но перед проверкой условия, если идти по синтаксису языка, следовательно, проверка будет провалена и будут выводиться все числа до 9; но по факту это не так.
Я новичок в JS, но хотелось бы сразу понимать что к чему... Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить почему так происходит?
Данный вопрос предназначен для понимания последовательности выполнения действий в циклах.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Отличие между циклами FOR в JS](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454790/%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-for-%d0%b2-js)

Comment: @Visman, здесь `continue` с меткой, немного другой все таки "for".

Comment: @Rolandius, ну и что, что с меткой, смысл от того вопроса не далеко ушел.

Comment: @Visman, не дубликат - там метки нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy, дубликат, так как той же самой командой меняется поведение цикла.

Comment: @Visman, не дубликат! Команда другая. `continue LABEL;` и `continue;` - это разные команды.

Comment: @Qwertiy, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue одна и та же команда!

Comment: @Visman, а давай ещё "один и тот же язык программирования - все вопросы дубликаты" ;)

Comment: Этот вопрос расчитан для того, что бы понять, как происходит действия в данном цикле, я расписал логику, как я понимаю, но в итоге все работатет по другому. Собственно и вопрос, как пошагово  данный цикл работает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В JS нет переходов по метке, но зато есть операторы `continue` и `break` которые на самом деле выглядят как `continue <метка>` и `break <метка>`.

В чём суть. Вы можете пометить цикл `for` или `while` меткой, например вот так:

```
label: for (;;) {
    // действия
}
```

Что происходит, когда интерпретатор находит `continue <метка>` в цикле. Если *метки нет*, он просто выполняет следующую итерацию. Если же она есть, то выполняет следующую итерацию цикла, помеченного этой меткой. Кстати, это единственный возможный способ в JS воздействовать из внутреннего цикла на внешний. Собственно, в этом и состоял Ваш вопрос (по `continue nextPrime;` выполнялась следующая итерация внешнего цикла).

Справедливости ради надо рассказать и про `break <метка>`. Если интерпретатор нашел этот оператор *без метки* в циклах `for` и `while`, то он прерывает выполнение цикла, в блоке `switch` - выходит из него. Главное отличие этого оператора от `continue <метка>` в том, что его можно использовать и вне блоков циклов и оператора switch, тогда писать метку обязательно и выделить меткой можно любой блок `{}`, например:

```
label: {
    console.log('1');
    break label;
    console.log('2');
}
```

В этом примере интерпретатор достигнув `break label;` найдет эту метку и перейдет в конец этого блока (`2` не выведется в консоль).

Answer (score 2):

Счетчик j внутреннего цикла "обнуляется" каждый раз, когда начинает выполняться внешний цикл.
Это наглядно можно увидеть, если открыть учебник из которого взят код выше и найти в теме "Циклы while и for" пример с меткой break. Если здесь внимательно посмотреть на то, как меняются i и j в окне prompt "Значение в координатах (0, 0)", то всё станет понятно.

Comment: И что по вашему стоит сделать?

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/487755)

Comment: @0xdb, код из вопроса работает верно, так что делать ничего не надо, надо лишь объяснить, почему он так работает.

Comment: @vantal, почему не содержится?